# Problem with table. Does not compile due to There are several problems at this line: -Extra }, or forgotten -Missing } inserted

Tags: tables

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{2}sb}
\hline
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3}
\textbf{Concept} & \textbf{Mathematical notation} & \textbf{Definition}
 \\\hline Graph &   \textit{G (N, $\pounds)} & Model for a network with a set of
 nodes connected by a set of ties \\
Node & \textit{N = {[n_1, n_2, n_3, , n_g]}} & Organizations depicted in the
graph\\
Tie & \textit{$\pounds = {[l_1, l_2, l_3, , l_L]}} & Undirected connection
between nodes\\
Size & \textit{G} & The number of nodes in the graph \\
Degree of a node & \textit{size of $\pounds} & The number of ties in a nod\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Concepts and measurements in network analysis}
\label{cha4:Tab:concepts}
\end{table}
```

Error:
There are several problems at this line:

> -Extra }, or forgotten $. \end{tabularx} (followed by: )
>
> -Missing } inserted. \end{tabularx} (followed by: )

Comment: There are some `$` missing.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this look like what you are looking for?  Also, could it be that you confused `\pounds` with `\mathcal{L}`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} *{2}{c} X @{}}
  \toprule
  \textbf{Concept} & \textbf{Mathematical notation}         & \textbf{Definition}                                                \\
  \midrule
  Graph            & $G (N, \pounds$)                       & Model for a network with a set of nodes connected by a set of ties \\
  Node             & $N = [n_1, n_2, n_3,\dots ,n_g]$       & Organizations depicted in the graph                                \\
  Tie              & $\pounds = [l_1, l_2, l_3,\dots ,l_L]$ & Undirected connection between nodes                                \\
  Size             & $G$                                    & The number of nodes in the graph                                   \\
  Degree of a node & size of $\pounds$                      & The number of ties in a nod                                        \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, Henri, thank you so much! It is exactly what I am looking for!

Comment: @MuratSartas If you like my answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](//tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and marking it as [accepted answer](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

Comment: Thanks again. I upvoted indeed but since I am new I think they dont show my voting.