# Extra } or forgotton $, Fatal error not compiling big table

Tags: tables, symbols

I am trying to make a big table presenting mostly numbers. When I do the table below, it gives a fatal error. Can you help me with it? Thanks!

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{bssssssssss}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Network characteristics}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Burundi}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{DRC}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Rwanda}}\\ \cline{3-11}

 &  & \textbf{T1} & \textbf{T2} & \textbf{\$Delta} & \textbf{T1} & \textbf{T2} &
\textbf{$\Delta} & \textbf{T1} & \textbf{T2} & \textbf{$\Delta} \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{=}{\textbf{Collaboration}} & \textbf{Size} & 120 & 100 & -17\% &
246 & 147 & -40\% &103 & 76 & -26\% \\\cline{2-11}
 & \textbf{Ties} & 202 & 183 & -9\% &
844 & 314 & -63\% &153 & 188 & 23\% \\\cline{2-11}
 & \textbf{With 1} & 183 & 129 & -30\% &
701 & 256 & -63\% &27 & 139 & 9\% \\\cline{2-11}
 & \textbf{With 2 or more} & 19 & 54 & 184\% &
143 & 58 & -59\% &26 & 4 & 88\% \\\cline{2-11}

\multirow{4}{=}{\textbf{Knowledge exchange}} 
& \textbf{Size} & 31 & 36 & 16\%
&34 & 24 & -29\% &23 & 25 & 9\% \\\cline{2-11}
 & \textbf{Ties} & 71 & 77 & 8\% &
189 & 69 & -63\% &43 & 79 & 84\% \\\cline{2-11}
 & \textbf{With 1} & 58 & 60 & -3\% &
152 & 60 & -61\% &37 & 55 & 49\% \\\cline{2-11}
 & \textbf{With 2+} & 13 & 17 & 31\% &
37 & 9 & -76\% &6 & 24 & 300\% \\\cline{2-11}

\multirow{4}{=}{\textbf{Influence spread}} & \textbf{Size} & 27 & 39 & 44\%
&41 & 15 & -63\% &22 & 21 & -5\% \\\cline{2-11}
 & \textbf{Ties} & 50 & 83 & 66\% &
207 & 51 & -75\% &43 & 67 & 56\% \\\cline{2-11}
 & \textbf{With 1} & 50 & 64 & 28\% &
170 & 47 & -72\% & 37 & 56 & 51\% \\\cline{2-11}
 & \textbf{With 2+} & 0 & 19 & N.A. &
37 & 4 & -89\% & 6 & 11 & 83 \\\cline{2-11}
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Changes in the collaboration, knowledge exchange, and influence spread
characteristics of multi-stakeholder networks in Burundi, DRC, and Rwanda}
\label{cha4:tab:chanceStatistics}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Well, copying your example into a simple article document doesn't compile (complaints about 's' columns). But have you tried commenting out the table contents and progressively uncommenting them? (hint: '$' comes in pairs)

Comment: Your usage of delta is wrong. Make sure, you use $/Delta$ instead. Isn't this question basically the same as your previous one? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/426277/134144

Comment: `$` is starting and ending inline math. For each opening `$` you have to put a closing `$` in there. As a result `$\Delta` is wrong and should be `$\Delta$`. Perhaps it would be better if you use `\(` and `\)` as inline math delimiters, which are added by LaTeX and might be easier to remember to use both for you.

Comment: Also the use of `tabularx` doesn't make much sense without an `X` type column. The `b` type column needs a width specified so should be something like `b{1cm}` and not just `b`. Also you're using the `s` column where you should use the `S` column. `s` is for columns which contain only a unit, `S` is for columns where you use numbers. And you should specify the unit of a column (e.g. `\%`) in the respective column head, not in each cell.

Comment: @remco `s` and `S` are column specifiers added by `siunitx`.

Comment: Also your code is not compilable as is. You should post a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), beginning at `\documentclass` and ending at `\end{document}`, including every package necessary to compile your code, but nothing unrelated to your problem!

Comment: @Skillmon But is it our job to figure that out? It could have been user-defined column types, for all I know (e.g. 'memoir' allows that)

Comment: @remco yes it could still be user defined and it is OPs job to show a complete MWE. I just know that those could be added by `siunitx`, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

How I would typeset your table:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{ll*3{*2{S[table-format=3]}S[table-format=-2]}}
  \toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Network characteristics} &
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Burundi} &
\multicolumn{3}{c}{DRC} &
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Rwanda}\\
\cmidrule(lr){3-5}
\cmidrule(lr){6-8}
\cmidrule(lr){9-11}

& & {T1} & {T2} & {$\Delta/\%$}
  & {T1} & {T2} & {$\Delta/\%$}
  & {T1} & {T2} & {$\Delta/\%$} \\
\midrule

Collabora- & Size    & 120 & 100 &    -17 & 246 & 147 & -40 & 103 &  76 & -26 \\
tion       & Ties    & 202 & 183 &     -9 & 844 & 314 & -63 & 153 & 188 &  23 \\
           & With 1  & 183 & 129 &    -30 & 701 & 256 & -63 &  27 & 139 &   9 \\
           & With 2+ &  19 &  54 &    184 & 143 &  58 & -59 &  26 &   4 &  88 \\
[1ex]
Knowledge  & Size    &  31 &  36 &     16 &  34 &  24 & -29 &  23 &  25 &   9 \\
exchange   & Ties    &  71 &  77 &      8 & 189 &  69 & -63 &  43 &  79 &  84 \\
           & With 1  &  58 &  60 &     -3 & 152 &  60 & -61 &  37 &  55 &  49 \\
           & With 2+ &  13 &  17 &     31 &  37 &   9 & -76 &   6 &  24 & 300 \\
[1ex]
Influence  & Size    &  27 &  39 &     44 &  41 &  15 & -63 &  22 &  21 &  -5 \\
spread     & Ties    &  50 &  83 &     66 & 207 &  51 & -75 &  43 &  67 &  56 \\
           & With 1  &  50 &  64 &     28 & 170 &  47 & -72 &  37 &  56 &  51 \\
           & With 2+ &   0 &  19 & {N.A.} &  31 &   4 & -89 &   6 &  11 &  83 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Changes in the collaboration, knowledge exchange, and influence spread
characteristics of multi-stakeholder networks in Burundi, DRC, and Rwanda}
\label{cha4:tab:chanceStatistics}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]